# If statements not rendering in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development. I decided to learn how to handle the slider. However, I am having some difficulty.

So I wrote some code that when the slider is at a minimum, the text displayed will be "Min Slider" and the same for the max.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var displayText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var editText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
var temp = "Text Goes Here"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func changeText(sender: AnyObject) {
    temp = editText.text
    displayText.text = temp
    editText.text = ""
}

@IBAction func textSize(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (slider.value == 0){
        displayText.text = "Min Slider"
    }
    if (slider.value == 2){
        displayText.text = "Max Slider"
    }
    else{
        displayText.text = temp
    }
}
}
```

However, when the slider is at a min it does not display the text. But it works with the max.
So, I tried:

```
@IBAction func textSize(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (slider.value == 2){
        displayText.text = "Max Slider"
    }
    if (slider.value == 0){
        displayText.text = "Min Slider"
    }
    else{
        displayText.text = temp
    }
}
```

Now the "Min Slider" works but not "Max Slider". It looks like the first if statement is not being rendered.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, if the slider value is at the minimum, the `if` branch of

```
if (slider.value == 0){
    displayText.text = "Min Slider"
}
```

is executed and then the `else` branch of

```
if (slider.value == 2){
    displayText.text = "Max Slider"
}
else{
    displayText.text = temp
}
```

so the text is overwritten immediately. What you probably want is

```
if (slider.value == 0){
    displayText.text = "Min Slider"
}
else if (slider.value == 2){   // "else if" here!
    displayText.text = "Max Slider"
}
else{
    displayText.text = temp
}
```

or better

```
if (slider.value == slider.minimumValue) {
    displayText.text = "Max Slider"
} else if (slider.value == slider.maximumValue) {
    displayText.text = "Min Slider"
} else {
    displayText.text = temp
}
```

to avoid the "magic numbers" `0` and `2` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The first if is being executed. The trouble is that the else clause in the second if is also being executed